# How to iterate through json array in Scala and apply API call for each json element

Tags: arrays, json, scala, api

```
[
  {
    "color": "#759c69",
    "studyId": "4455",
    "value": "Asparagus"
  },
  {
    "color": "#e68cb9",
    "studyId": "4455",
    "value": "Awesome"
  },
  {
    "color": "#6e665d",
    "studyId": "4455",
    "value": "Bear Hug"
  },
  {
    "color": "#5d7ed6",
    "studyId": "4455",
    "value": "Blue Eyes"
  }
]
```

I want to iterate through JSON array in Scala and apply API call for each JSON element. How can I do it in Scala?

Comment: Pick a **Json** library _(there are many opetions. e.g. **circe**, **play-json**, **upickle**, **jsonitter-scala**, etc)_. Search how to `decode` a **String** into a **List[CaseClasse]** in that library. Call `foreach` or whatever on that **List**.

Comment: Alternatively, pick a JSON library with JSON optics support and run `fold` which would execute side effects for each element. Depends on whether or not you need to understand the context in which each element appeared.

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser._


object Demo1 extends App {

  case class Param(color: String, studyId: String, value: String)

  val str =
    """[
      |   {
      |      "color":"#759c69",
      |      "studyId":"4455",
      |      "value":"Asparagus"
      |   },
      |   {
      |      "color":"#e68cb9",
      |      "studyId":"4455",
      |      "value":"Awesome"
      |   },
      |   {
      |      "color":"#6e665d",
      |      "studyId":"4455",
      |      "value":"Bear Hug"
      |   },
      |   {
      |      "color":"#5d7ed6",
      |      "studyId":"4455",
      |      "value":"Blue Eyes"
      |   }
      |]""".stripMargin

  val obj = decode[List[Param]](str)

  println(obj.getOrElse(Param("", "", "")))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many json libraries. For example you can take a look at [Scala json parsers performance](https://github.com/yanns/scala-json-parsers-performance), to see the usage and performance. I'll demonstrate how that can be done using [play-json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson). We need to first create a case class that represents your data model:

```
case class Entity(color: String, studyId: String, value: String)
```

Now we need to create a formatter, on the [companion object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/companion-objects.html):

```
object Entity {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Entity] = Json.format[Entity]
}
```

Assuming the json string in the question is located as `jsonString`, we can create a [JsValue](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsValue.html) from it:

```
val entitiesResult = Json.parse(jsonString)
```

And convert it into a model:

```
entitiesResult.validate[Seq[Entity]] match {
  case JsSuccess(entities, _) =>
    entities.foreach(println) // Do here the API call you want
  case JsError(errors) =>
    println(errors) // handle json errors here
}
```

A complete running example can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/bWb68HpCTfO92IIMSzK5Ww/1). Just don't forget to add play-json as a dependency, by adding the following to your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "play-json" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-json"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.9.1"
```